# How do I implement a default functionality for HTTP Method in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I am using JAX-RS and it has default implementations for `@OPTIONS` and `@HEAD` methods, but I would like to provide a different functionality.

What I have done currently is this:

```java
@GET
@Path("path/to/resource")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response resourceCall(){
    // Normal method implementation
}

@OPTIONS
@Path("path/to/resource")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response resourceCall(){
    Response.status(Response.Status.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED).build();
}
```

So basically I create a new call to each one of my resources. But I would like to have a *catch-all* method here that would treat all my calls to `@OPTION` or to `@HEAD`.

How do I implement such functionality?

**EDIT**

Just for clarity. I know how to do this using a Servlet Filter but I am wondering if `JAX-RS` has a similar feature built-in for th is specific case.

Comment: What JAX-RS implementation are you using?

Comment: _"I know how to do this using a Servlet Filter but I am wondering if JAX-RS has a similar feature"_ - JAX-RS has filters also.

Comment: @peeskillet I am using Jersey. I think I did a poor job expressing myself. What I mean is that I wanted to find out if JAX-RS has a feature where I can implement a default generic method for a specific HTTP verb.

Comment: No, but Jersey has a feature where you can add an OPTIONS to every endpoint, without having to touch your resource classes. See [this example in the documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/resource-builder.html#d0e11315)

Comment: Oh, that's the functionality I was looking for. Thank you very much. If you'd like to provide an answer on that I would gladly accept it as the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Jersey, Jersey has a feature that allows you to [programmatically add and modify resources](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/resource-builder.html#d0e11315). So you could add `OPTIONS` and `HEAD` methods to all your resources, without having to touch your resource classes. Below is an example that does nothing but send a 405 with a `No <Method>` message. Probably not what you want, but you should be able to figure out what you need to modify to get what you want.

```
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Configuration;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import org.glassfish.jersey.process.Inflector;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelProcessor;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Resource;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceModel;

@Provider
public class HeadAndOptionsModelProcessor implements ModelProcessor {

    @Override
    public ResourceModel processResourceModel(ResourceModel resourceModel,
            Configuration configuration) {
        ResourceModel.Builder resourceModelBuilder = new ResourceModel.Builder(false);
        for (Resource rootResource: resourceModel.getResources()) {
            final Resource.Builder rootResourceBuilder = Resource.builder(rootResource);
            addOptions(rootResourceBuilder);
            addHead(rootResourceBuilder);

            for (Resource childResource: rootResource.getChildResources()) {
                final Resource.Builder childResourceBuilder = Resource.builder(childResource);
                addOptions(childResourceBuilder);
                addHead(childResourceBuilder);
                rootResourceBuilder.addChildResource(childResourceBuilder.build());
            }
            resourceModelBuilder.addResource(rootResourceBuilder.build());
        }
        return resourceModelBuilder.build();
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceModel processSubResource(ResourceModel subResourceModel,
            Configuration configuration) {
        return subResourceModel;
    }

    private void addOptions(Resource.Builder resourceBuilder) {
        resourceBuilder.addMethod("OPTIONS")
                .handledBy(new Inflector<ContainerRequestContext, Response>() {
                    @Override
                    public Response apply(ContainerRequestContext context) {
                        return getOptionsResponse(context);
                    }
                }).produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).extended(true);
    }

    private void addHead(Resource.Builder resourceBuilder) {
        resourceBuilder.addMethod("HEAD")
                .handledBy(new Inflector<ContainerRequestContext, Response>() {
                    @Override
                    public Response apply(ContainerRequestContext context) {
                        return getHeadResponse(context);
                    }
                }).produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).extended(true);
    }

    private static Response getOptionsResponse(ContainerRequestContext context) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED).entity("No Options").build();
    }

    private static Response getHeadResponse(ContainerRequestContext context) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED).entity("No Head").build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Default options handler is implemented via

```
@OPTIONS
@Path("{path: .*}")
public Response allOptions() {
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work, should I write it on a superclass or something?